# CSS column-count works but wish to control where it breaks the column

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, column-count

I use a WordPress plugin called Event List which lists events (with text and pictures) on any page with the help of a shortcode - [event-list].

The list is displayed in a long row and I've been struggling to try and make it display in columns. Asked the author of the plugin and he just responded: "it could probably be done with `CSS`". So I tried and found the column-count property which is GREAT and does exactly what I want, bar for one thing...

I know it balances the columns automatically so it splits columns on less desirable lines. It will leave the date at the bottom of the page on column 1 and the picture for the event starts on the top of the page in column 2. I currently use this simple code:

```
<style>
.split {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
     -moz-column-count: 2;
          column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-width: 500px;
     -moz-column-width: 500px;
          column-width: 500px;
}
</style>
```

and for html I use:

```
<div class="split">[event-list]</div>
```

I'm thinking css is not optimal for this and should instead use JavaScript but that is out of my league.

Comment: Can you post the HTML output of `[event-list]`?

Comment: Please excuse me, I'm quite a novice. How would I go about finding the HTML output for the [event list]? Inspection tool? This is the plugin in question https://wordpress.org/plugins/event-list/

Answer (score 0):

That is not full answer, rather a remarque. Yes, it can be achieved with Javascript inside plugin EventList ... . May be your text would be prettier look if you add something like

```
.split p {
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.split img {
 display: block; 
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Very much appreciate the effort, unfortunately it did not do any difference. I might have to be brave and dive into the world of java :)